# What does var x = x || {} ;

Tags: javascript

what does the following code do in java script:

```
var x = x || {};
```

Comment: This question is the older one, the other is a duplicate.

Comment: Logical expressions in JavaScript are evaluated left to right and they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules: false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false. true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true. In the example above, if x is true, x becomes the value assigned. If x is false or undefined, the second operand becomes the assignment which is {}.

Answer (score 45):

`||` is the logical `OR`.

The expression

```
var x = x OR {};
```

should become more obvious then.

If `x` has a **falsy** value (like `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`), we assign `x` an empty object `{}`, otherwise just keep the current value. The long version of this would look like

```
var x = x ? x : {};
```

Comment: excellent answer. i am a c programmer and this didnt make any sense.

Comment: If this didn't make any sense for you, then you might also watch out for `!!value` which returns a boolean representing the truthfulness of `value`, very handy at times.

Comment: Your long version is incorrect: consider the case when x has previously defined and is set to `null`. `var x = x || {};` will redefine x to an object, whereas `var x = (typeof x !== 'undefined') ? x : {};` will not. The paragraph preceding it is correct though.

Comment: @Tim: true, I forgot about the `typeof null === 'object'` enigma.

Answer (score 8):

If `x` is undefined (or null, or any other `false` value), it becomes an empty object.

Answer (score 5):

One should never write "var x = x || {};" per se.

The only circumstance where this is not identical to "var x = {};" is when x was previously initialized in the same scope. That is immoral. Note:

```
function() {
  x = {foo:"bar"};
  var x = x || {};
}
```

Is the same as, merely more confusing than,

```
function() {
  var x = {foo:"bar"};
  x = x || {};
}
```

In neither case is there any reference to the value of the symbol "x" in the global scope.

This expression is a confused variant of the legitimate lazy property initialization idiom:

```
function( foo ) { 
  foo.x = foo.x || {};
  foo.x.y = "something";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign `x` to a new empty object if it is `null` (undefined, false) or keep it's existing value if not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

unless x is defined or assigned a value it will take empty object as default value..

that is,

```
for example
x = 10
var x = x || {};
```

output must be

```
10
```

if x value not assigned. the output value must be,

```
undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

if var x is defined then it will be that defined value. Else it will be empty object like `[object Object]`

For example, in the following code block, x will be `10`:

```
var x = 10;
x = x || {}
```

However, if:

```
var x = x || {};
```

then `x` will be `[object Object]`