# What does this mean?: x || x === {}

Tags: javascript

Does the following:

```
x || x === {}
```

not mean `!!x`, that is, `x` is defined?

Comment: this might help a bit ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563153/what-does-var-x-x

Comment: Since `{}` is truthy, I don't see the point of the above code...

Comment: it is not a dupe, because of the comparison.

Comment: The writer probably wanted to ask that if x is an empty object. but it's reference wise

Comment: @Daniel Krom What should they have written in this case?

Comment: @Baz: Who is "they"? Where did you actually see this? Or are you really just trying to ask some other question?

Comment: To check empty object: `Object.keys(x).length == 0` or (DONT DO THAT) `JSON.stringify(x) === "{}"` you can also use compare functions \ libraries (deep compare) and ask `deepEqual(x,{})`

Comment: @@Daniel Krom By "they" I am referring to "the writer" of this expression. I have seen this expression used in the code I'm working on and I didn't understand it. You wrote: "The writer probably wanted to ask that if x is an empty object. but it's reference wise"

Comment: uhm, I'm not sure if it was supposed to be a comparison - it'd be unreasonable anyway, since a falsy value (only type for which `x` wouldn't be returned) is never equal to any object, so it'd be `false` anyway

Comment: I'd be very curious about the original context where this was found. Looks more like a non-JS programmer guessing at how the language works, or some other code misrepresented, like `x = x || {}`, which is *very* common.

Answer (score 7):

That comparison makes no sense, because either `x` is truthy, then you get the result of `x`,  or falsy, you get `false` (a falsy value is never strict equal to an empty object instance).

A concise version would be

```
x || false
```

for give me `x` or `false`.

Comment: You will get false in the right side because x is compared as a reference with {}. @Tomasz Lewowski specified that too below.

Comment: @RazvanDumitru This is why she wrote `false`

Comment: Of course, but for a beginner it's somehow ambiguous to go directly to the final result.

Comment: You are correct but I'd like to generalize your last statement: _Nothing_ is ever strict equal to an empty object literal.

Answer (score 5):

`x || x === {}` means basically `x || false`.

`!!x` means "is `x` truthy", so it's not exactly the same - `x || x === {}` will return `x` if `x` is truthy.
In the same case, `!!x` will return `true`.

`||` operator means "if left side is truthy (not `null`, not `undefined`, not `0` etc. - see [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript) for details) return left side, else return right side".

On the right side you have `x === {}` which always evaluates to `false`, since strict comparison means comparing reference-wise (i.e., "is `x` the same object as `{}`, which is never true)

`!!x` and `x || x === {}` will be the same only if `x === true` or `x === false`

Answer (score 2):

`||` returns the left hand side if the LHS is a true value. So if `x` is a true value, it returns `x`.

Otherwise, it compares `x` to a new object, which will always be `false`, and returns that.

So if `x` is true, you get (an unmodified) `x` otherwise you get an explicit boolean `false`.

This is different to `!!x` since that would return a boolean `true` if `x` was a true value.